# Link https://kforge.ros.org/megaslam/imu_filter does not work

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
Wanted to download package imu_filter (http://wiki.ros.org/action/login/imu_filter) source code

and the source link https://kforge.ros.org/megaslam/imu_filter does not work.

Any suggestions or alternative link from where the source code can be downloaded?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206765/link-https://kforge.ros.org/megaslam/imu_filter-does-not-work/) by [StupuAlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22101/stupualin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

kforge was shut down a while ago, and I don't believe that megaslam was ever moved to github. I suggest looking at http://wiki.ros.org/imu_filter_madgwick as an equivalent package.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2015-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1